# Change "display:none" to "display:flex" when you press enter in the input field

Tags: jquery

How can I change `display:none` to `display:flex` to my div when I click enter in my first input field in the div?

Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/NA9eJjM5

```
<div class="checkoutDiv" style=" display:flex;">
<input type="text" name="ean" id="focus" placeholder="Баркод" style="width: 250px; margin:10px;" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
<input type="text" name="num" value="1" style="width: 50px; margin:0; text-align: center;">
</div>

<div class="checkoutDiv" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="ean" placeholder="Баркод" style="width: 250px; margin:10px;" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
<input type="text" name="num" value="1" style="width: 50px; margin:0; text-align: center;">
</div>

<div class="checkoutDiv" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="ean" placeholder="Баркод" style="width: 250px; margin:10px;" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
<input type="text" name="num" value="1" style="width: 50px; margin:0; text-align: center;">
</div>


<script>
function callback(e){
if (
    $(this).index() == $('#checkout div[display="flex"]').length - 1
        &&
    e.which == 13
) {
    $(this).next('div[display="none"]').prop("display", "flex").keypress(callback)
    }
}

$('#checkout div[display="none"]').keypress(callback)
</script>
```

These Div's are in `<div id="checkout">`

Edit:

I changed it to:

```
function callback(e){
    if (
        $(this).index() == $('.checkoutDiv').attr('style', 'display: flex').length - 1
            &&
        e.which == 13
    ) {
        $(this).next('.checkoutDiv').attr('style', 'display: flex').keypress(callback).focus();
    }
}

$('.checkoutDiv').keypress(callback)
```

but it changes the display attribute to all next divs with class checkoutDiv.. How to make it to change the display to next div only?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. there are a number of issues with your code, yet to start, the Selector is incorrect. `div[display="flex"]` and `div[display="none"]` are not correct selectors, these are not attributes of the element. They are parts of the Style attribute.

Comment: How to change the style attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Classes to assign your Styles instead of using the style attribute. This gives you more ability to manage and select elements in your script.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  function callback(e) {
    if ($(this).index() == $('#checkout div.flex').is(":last") &&
      e.which == 13) {
      $("#checkout div.hidden:eq(0)").toggleClass("hidden flex");
      $("div.flex").last().find("input:eq(0)").addClass("focus").focus();
    }
  }

  $('#checkout').on("keypress", ".focus", callback);
})
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkout">
  <div class="checkoutDiv flex">
    <input type="text" name="ean" class="focus" placeholder="Баркод" style="width: 250px; margin:10px;" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
    <input type="text" name="num" value="1" style="width: 50px; margin:0; text-align: center;">
  </div>

  <div class="checkoutDiv hidden">
    <input type="text" name="ean" placeholder="Баркод" style="width: 250px; margin:10px;" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
    <input type="text" name="num" value="1" style="width: 50px; margin:0; text-align: center;">
  </div>

  <div class="checkoutDiv hidden">
    <input type="text" name="ean" placeholder="Баркод" style="width: 250px; margin:10px;" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
    <input type="text" name="num" value="1" style="width: 50px; margin:0; text-align: center;">
  </div>
</div>
```

As I mentioned, there are lots of changes.

I updated the IF statement to make use of `.is()` to make sure the event was happening on the last input.

To ensure the that the callback was used for  all of them as needed, I used `.on()` which can delegate the callback.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/is/
- https://api.jquery.com/on/
- https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/